# css not working on code igniter

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i recently debugged all the errors on the connection of my headers css and js, there are no errors anymore, but css still isnt working. but the format of my view is changed, but not as i wanted.

login.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {


    public function index(){


        $data['main_content'] = 'login_view';
        $this->load->view('includes/viewtemplates',$data);



    }
```

viewTemplates.php

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header'); ?>
<?php $this->load->view($main_content); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer'); ?>
```

header.php

```
<!--DOCTYPE html-->

<html lang="en">


<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>public/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>public/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">

        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>public/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>public/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<header>
</header>
```

bootstrap-responsive.min.css

```
 body {

    background: #F0F0F0 ;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'times-new roman';

 }

#login_form {

    width: 300px;
    background: 3333FF;
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    padding: 1em;
    -moz-border-radius:  4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {

    margin-top = 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: 000033;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0;
}
```

Comment: Check if the path is correct

Comment: what is your base_url ?? You should check if the path is correct .

Comment: i recently have errors with the path. i already fixed it. so i dont have any ideas yet why it isnt working. i am new at setting up code igniter.

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem in website images it will not load correctly 

you can use base tag for this(you need to add `<base>` tag in `<head>`) ...

```
<base href="<?php echo base_url();?>public/">
```

and make sure image floder is in public directory

Comment: so ill change the  <link> tag to <base href> ??

Comment: like this 
`<base>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>public/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>public/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">

  <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>public/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>public/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
</base>`

Comment: `<head><base href="<?php echo base_url();?>public/"></head>`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have to loaded the **URL Helper Class** in your controller or in `autoload.php` because to use `base_url()` (shorthand) you need to load URL Helper

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Than you can use shorthand `base_url()`:

```
<?php echo base_url();?>
```

And i didn't see the **URL** helper loaded in your controller.

Also check **HTML** view source and hit the **URL** you will get the better understanding.

---

You can also check either ending slash **/** available in `base_url()` or not

This will also not work, if your URL looks like this:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>public/js/jquery.js"></script> 
// example.compublic/js...
```

Comment: $autoload['helper'] = array('url','form'); i already have the url autoload.

Comment: and i find this one which is NOT my css in the elements section.

Comment: `
element.style {
}
indexmedia="screen"
body {
    background: white;
    font-family: arial;
}
indexmedia="screen"
@media (max-width: 979px)
body {
    padding-top: 0;
}
indexmedia="screen"
@media (max-width: 767px)
body {
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
user agent stylesheetbody {
    display: block;
    margin: 8px;
}`

Comment: @kev_m: echo base_url(); check the what is the url?

Comment: url of what? url of what?

Comment: @kev_m: echo base_url() and check what r u getting?